# What is the meaning/cause of this extra entry in the output of `ip address` when another device connects to the network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ip, ipv6

I was recently trying to set up an [EspressIf Border Router](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-thread-br/en/latest/hardware_platforms.html) for my network. After flashing the device and letting it boot, a single-machine Kubernetes host on my network restarted all of its pods (!).

After some digging, I found that this was caused by a network change:

> microk8s.daemon-apiserver-kicker[1653]: CSR change detected. Reconfiguring the kube-apiserver

I was able to prevent this by setting an explicit `--bind-address=0.0.0.0` in Kubernetes, however I'm trying to understand why booting the border router (which I expect to just be another device on the network) was triggering something Kubernetes thinks it should restart all pods over.

I ran `ip address` before and after booting the BR, and the difference is this new entry under `enp2s0f0`:

```
2: enp2s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:7c:3f:f2:08:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    // The two lines below are new
    inet6 fdde:ad00:beef:cafe:3e7c:3fff:fef2:8b1/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1702sec preferred_lft 1702sec
```

I'm failing to understand what this entry really means (in particular, why it appeared, and what impact it has on the local networking to understand whether Kubernetes was being overly-agressive or if restarting was a reasonable action).

My first thought was that maybe the BR included a DHCP server. I did find some DHCP settings and turned them off, but it made no difference (I suspect maybe it was for the Thread side?).

Comment: https://components.espressif.com/components/espressif/esp_ot_cli_extension

Comment: [Router advertisement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol#Functions) is enough to get a node to add an IPv6 address and route(s) if this node is configured to follow RA.

Comment: @A.B that explains it (and matches the response I got at https://github.com/espressif/esp-thread-br/issues/45). Given this, microk8s restarting all pods seems quite agressive so I've opened https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/4317 to see if that's really expected. If you post as an answer, I'll accept it so it's clear this question has been answered. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely cause of the observed symptom: a new IPv6 address appears on a node (which happens to be running microk8s) in the LAN after booting an IPv6 router on the same LAN is that the router sent Router Advertisements (RA) as [described in RFC 4861](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4861#section-3) about Neighbor Discovery Protocol:

> Neighbor Discovery defines five different ICMP packet types: A pair of
> Router Solicitation and Router Advertisement messages [...]
>
> - Router Advertisement: Routers advertise their presence together with various link and Internet parameters either periodically, or in
>   response to a Router Solicitation message. Router Advertisements
>   contain prefixes that are used for determining whether another address
>   shares the same link (on-link determination) and/or address
>   configuration, a suggested hop limit value, etc.

and the Linux system added a new IPv6 address on the interface having received the RA. This is intended to be built-in at low level (no DHCPv6 needed): Linux  when [configured to accept RAs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n2087) handles this in kernel (with the possible exception of "DNS RA options"), following associated [RFC 4862](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4862#section-4) (IPv6 Stateless Address Autoconfiguration):

> The next phase of autoconfiguration involves obtaining a Router
> Advertisement or determining that no routers are present.  If routers
> are present, they will send Router Advertisements that specify what
> sort of autoconfiguration a host can do. [...]

> Because routers generate Router Advertisements periodically, hosts
> will continually receive new advertisements.  Hosts process the
> information contained in each advertisement as described above, adding
> to and refreshing information received in previous advertisements.

It appears then that microk8s when also handling IPv6 reacts to such network configuration change (which is something reasonable) in a way that disrupts running pods in OP's case (which is something less reasonable). I don't know if this reaction for OP's specific setup is to be expected or to be considered as a bug.